# $T(X)$ be the set of all function $f :X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$.Then which of the following statement is True?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a  set $X$, let $\mathcal{P}(X)$  be the set of all  subsets of $X$  and $T(X)$  be  the  set of all function $f: X \to \{0,1\}$.
Then which  of the  following statement is True ?

1. If  $X$ is  finite ,then  $P(X)$ is  finite
2. There is one-one correspondence between $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$

**My Approach**

I  take  $X = N$  then  I get $\mathcal{P}(X) = 2^N$   which is uncountable so option a) is  discarded  i mean  option $a)$ is not correct

im doubt in option  2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping between a set and its power set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696018/mapping-between-a-set-and-its-power-set)