# Mapping between a set and its power set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

For a set $X$, let $P(X)$ be the set of all subsets of $X$ and $\Omega(X)$ be the set of all functions from $f:X \to \{0,1\}$. Then

$(1)$ If $X$ is finite , then $P(X)$ is finite

$(2)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are finite  and if there is a one-one correspondence between $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$, then there is a one-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$

$(3)$ There is no one-one correspondence between $X$ and $P(X)$

$(4)$ There is a one_one correspondence between $\Omega(X)$ and $P(X)$

My attempt:-

$(1)$ is true.

$(3)$ True by Cantor's Theorem

I know there are answers to $(4)$ on this site but I am specially interested in $(2)$ which I know to be true.

Let $f:P(X) \to P(Y)$ be a one-one correspondence. Since $X$ and $Y$ are finite we have $|P(X)|=|P(Y)|\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$ otherwise $|P(X)|\neq P(Y)|$. Since X and Y are finite sets with same no. of elements , there is a bijection . Is this a good enough proof? Can this be  generalized to two infinite sets having a one-one correspondence between their power sets.

Thanks for your thoughts and time.

Comment: I think you mean that $\Omega(X)$ is the set of all functions $f : X \to [0, 1].$ Otherwise, by the Pigeonhole Principle, for $|X| > 2,$ there cannot be an injection (i.e., a 1-1 map) $f : X \to \{0, 1\}.$

Comment: From what I can tell, your proof of (2.) is fine. If $X$ and $Y$ are finite, then $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ are finite, hence if $f : P(X) \to P(Y)$ is a bijection (i.e., a 1-1 correspondence), then we must have that $|P(X)| = |P(Y)|$ so that $|X| = |Y|$ (take $\log_2$ of $|P(X)| = |P(Y)|$). Finite sets with the same cardinality must be in bijection.

Comment: @Carlo {0,1} is correct

Comment: @ℋolo, I am not familiar with this construction. I suppose we don't care about if the maps are injective, then.

Comment: what is the meaning of $1-1$ correspondence?Bijection or surjection?

Answer (score 2):

The proof is not good enough, you have said that $|P(X)|=|P(Y)|\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$, otherwise $|P(X)|≠|P(Y)|$, why is that "otherwise" part true?

> you can prove that for finite $X$, we have $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$, then you really get that $|X|≠|Y|$ implies $|P(X)|≠|P(Y)|$

This result cannot work on infinite sets, as it is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency)(by [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem)) that it is even possible that $P(\aleph_n)=P(\aleph_k)$ for all $n,k∈\Bbb N$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, and there exists a bijection $P(X) \to P(Y),$ hence we have that $2^{|X|} = |P(X)| = |P(Y)| = 2^{|Y|}.$ Of course, this implies that $|X| = |Y|.$

Comment: @Carlo $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$ is something you need to prove, and I don't know from their proof that that they know that fact, so it is not good enough yet.

Everything is "of course" when you know the way already

Comment: @ℋolo..Thanks sir , I am trying to understand your answer. Can you please tell what is $\Bbb N_k$ ?

Comment: @student see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number), $\aleph_k$ is the $k^{th}$ smallest infinite cardinal

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer will help you a lot.

Given that $~~P(X):$  set of all subsets of $X$ 
 $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Ω(X):$ set of all functions $~f:X→\{0,1\}$

For **option** $\bf(1)$, if $X$ is finite, let $|X|=n$, then $|P(X)|=2^n$ which is again finite. Hence option $(1)$ is true.

For **option** $\bf(2)$, let $X$ and $Y$ are finite and there is one-one correspondence between $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$.$$\implies |P(X)|=|P(Y)|\implies 2^{|X|}=2^{|Y|}\implies |X|=|Y|$$Hence there exists one-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$. Thus option $(2)$ is true.

For **option** $\bf(3)$, since $~|P(X)|=2^{|X|}\gt|X|~$
Thus there is no one-one correspondence between $X$ and $P(X)$. Therefore option $(3)$ is true.

For **option** $\bf(4)$, since $~|P(X)|=2^{|X|}=|\Omega(X)|~$
Therefore there exists a one-one correspondence between $\Omega(X)$ and $P(X)$. Therefore option $(4)$ is true.